# Delete git.io shortened URL

Tags: url, github

I wanted to shorten my GitHub repo's URL using git.io. I wanted a custom name but accidentally used their automatic name, which is full of random characters.

How can I revert this and get a new one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If someone else created it first, it will return the existing shortened URL. So, it is currently not possible to override but you can contact GitHub support team to either remove or change it.

I discovered following trick though, you can add a harmless query param `?` to make it different:

```
$ curl -i https://git.io -F "url=YOUR_GITHUB_URL_HERE?" -F "code=YOUR_CUSTOM_NAME"
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that as of Sep 2020 GitHub Support is no longer releasing git.io URLs:

https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-23-git-io-urls-no-longer-released-by-github-support/

Answer (score 2):

if the URL has a shortener on git.io already you can still create a new one by adding /index.html or JUST the forward slash /

ex. github https://github.com/jgorset/git.io/issues/5 >> https://git.io/vxba7
now you can still create vanity shortener with --code=NAME, adding a forward slash to URL as https://github.com/jgorset/git.io/issues/5/

Comment: The `/` is a forward slash, not a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the url with the .html ending (or the opposite if you already shortened it). For example, if you did this before:

`$ curl https://git.io -F "url=https://X.github.io/pages/page" -F "code=CODE"`

You could try using this if you don't mind people seeing the `.html` extension:

`$ curl https://git.io -F "url=https://X.github.io/pages/page.html" -F "code=CODE"`

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2022 the ability to shorten URLs via the Git.io URL shortener has been removed.  This tool is slated for deprecation in the future, and users are encouraged to use other URL shortening services.

Per [The GitHub Blog](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-11-git-io-no-longer-accepts-new-urls/):

> You can no longer create new URLs on [git.io](https://git.io/). Existing URLs will continue to be accessible, but we encourage using one of the many URL shortening services that are available, instead of git.io, as we will be deprecating the tool in the future.

The [www.git.io](https://www.git.io) website (but not the [git.io](https://git.io) one linked to by the above blog post) has a message regarding this removal:

> Sorry, we're no longer accepting new links to shorten.

[image: www.git.io site with message "Sorry, we're no longer accepting new links to shorten."]

Comment: the blog post url 404s. WTF github...

Comment: They are the same urls

Comment: @StarkBots One has "www." but the other doesn't: [https://www.git.io/](https://www.git.io/) vs. [https://git.io/](https://git.io/).

Comment: @M.Justin Are they different? Like: `https://www.github.com/` and  `https://www.github.com/` or `https://google.com` and `https://www.google.com/`. I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: @StarkBots I suspect they're supposed to be the same thing.  Looks like however that message was configured, it wasn't properly configured to be at both versions of that URL.

Comment: @M.Justin Now I think they are not same. Maybe it's a subdomain cause I tried on other subdomains and it doesn't work. Like `https://users.rust-lang.org` will work but `https://www.users.rust-lang.org` obviously not. Thanks. Anyway it's far-fetched and off-topic now.